# Lync Presence: namectrl Permission denied issue in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, lync

I have created Lync Presence and successfully integrated in my SharePoint site. And its works file in my environment.

When i have deployed solution to production server it shows error in **namectrl.ShowOOUI** method.

> **Permission denied**

Error looks like this. And also not work in **Firefox** in production which also works in my environment

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on issue finally i found solution that i am accessing production site from different domain then production domain thats why i got this error.

**Everything works great if we add the domain on IE to trusted sites.**

IE requires that the domain be added to trusted sites.

To add domain in trusted sites.

**IE settings > Internet Options > Security tab, 
add your SharePoint site to trusted sites and uncheck protected mode.**

> One workaround is to host the Silverlight application on a server that users have access to. Then you only need trust that server.

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c39070b0-385f-4bb1-b0c4-f4698f3689ee/lync-presence-indicator-and-trusted-sites?forum=communicatorsdk)